# Edit text didn't show up in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new at android also stackoverflow.

I made layout like this picture below.

However, when I run this with vda then I can't see those `EditText` and a `TextView`.

Anybody can give me some advice?

Thank you for your time.

[image: Linear Layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idText"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="아이디"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pwText"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="비밀번호"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:text="로그인"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="회원가입"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />
```

Comment: Also include `xml` code of this `layout` in question

Comment: @SnehaChandiyekar Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn more about `ConstraintLayout` from scratch, please read this document
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

ELSE

You can use `LinearLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` for simple UI.

Comment: I changed it to relative layout then it works! Thank you so much for your advice nabs.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are using `ConstraintLayout`, so, if you put views as child of `ConstraintLayout` you must set rules to show them.

PD. Paste your xml code used to make this view

Comment: How can I set rules? Would you give some advice??

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `ConstraintLayout` for displaying the EditText, so set the constraint for the view (EditText). 
A sample of code for a view in `ConstraintLayout` is as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

I put these lines but still doesn't work. Could you give me more hint?

Comment: follow this link: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#adjust-the-constraint-bias